# Dynamic Programming, Traversal Method

Tags: c++, dynamic

```
int fib(int numb){
    vector<int> temp;
    int str;
    if(numb==0 || numb==1){
        return numb;
    }
    else{
        str=(fib(numb-1)+fib(numb-2));
        temp.push_back(str);
        return str;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<temp.size();i++){
    if(temp[i]==numb){
            return temp[i];
        }}
```

Fibonacci function and it work but how do I check if the for loop part of the function really works? Its for a traversal method of finding a existing number and returning it instead of processing another recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop can't possibly work. It will never work. Because there's no way to get to the loop. Every code path before the loop ends with a `return` statement.

Walk through your code, statement by statement, and see for yourself that your code will never reach the loop.

Comment: How can I make it reach the loop?

Comment: Delete one of the returns ... ;)

Answer (score 0):

You must process the stored elements **before** returning any value. More, as you store elements in vector during recursive calls, the vector `temp` must be static.

And the research should not be that: you should store in the vector the values, said differently, what you want it `temp[i]` is `fib(i)`.

A simple way to do that is to make use that C++ allows initializing of static values through functions. You could then initialize `temp` to { 0, 1}, and when asked for a value, just look if the number is higher than `temp.size`:

- if it is, compute it and store it into `temp` - as you compute them with values of fib(n-1) and fib(n-2), when you compute it you know that the `temp` vector already contains fib(n-1), and does not still contains fib(n) => you have just to push it back into `temp`
- it not just extract it from `temp`

Code could be:

```
// return a temporary vector containing 0 and 1
std::vector<int> inifib() {
    std::vector<int> t;
    t.push_back(0);
    t.push_back(1);
    return t;
}
int fib(unsigned int numb) {
    static std::vector<int> temp = inifib(); // initialize once the static temp with size 2 and values 0,1
    if (numb >= temp.size()) {
        int cr = fib(numb-1) + fib(numb - 2);
        temp.push_back(cr); // when we are here, temp contains everything up to fib(numb - 1) - just push
    }
    return temp[numb];
}
```

Comment: @Testermoon01: what were input and output?

Comment: The program is okay, I just removed the static type for the vector hoping that I wouldnt need it and its more fast computing now instead of manual recursive method